# Hiding Div tag when the selection is not selected

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my JavaScript code. Since I am not really kin into this, I need a help figuring it out why my `div` is not hiding. First, when I click *Primary* or *Secondary*, it's doing fine and *Senior high* as well. If I click *Tertiary*, the text-field *Senior Course* under *Senior High School* displays again. It should only display text-field *Tertiary Course*. Now when I select back the *Senior High School*, the display should only be text-field *Senior Course*. What happens here is now is both text-field *Senior Course* and text-field *Tertiary Course* is still visible. It's supposed to be hidden when its not selected.

```js
function showDiv(select) {
  if (select.value == 'Tertiary') {
    if (select.value == 'Tertiary') {
      document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "none";
    }
  } else if (select.value == 'Senior High School') {
    if (select.value == 'Senior High School') {
      document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Level:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="test" onchange="showDiv(this)" name="ship_level"><option value="Primary">Primary</option><option value="Secondary">Secondary</option><option value="Senior High School">Senior High School</option><option value="Tertiary">Tertiary</option></select>
</div>
<div id="hidden_Tertiary" style="display: none;" class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Tertiary Course:</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You Want" name="ship_course_Tertiary" type="text">
</div>
<div id="hidden_Senior" style="display: none;" class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Senior Course:</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You asdasdWant" name="ship_course_Senior" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide/show the divs on every change

```js
function showDiv(select) {
  document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "none";
  if (select.value == 'Tertiary') {
    if (select.value == 'Tertiary') {
      document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "none";
    }
  } else if (select.value == 'Senior High School') {
    if (select.value == 'Senior High School') {
      document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Level:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="test" onchange="showDiv(this)" name="ship_level"><option value="Primary">Primary</option><option value="Secondary">Secondary</option><option value="Senior High School">Senior High School</option><option value="Tertiary">Tertiary</option></select>
</div>

<div id="hidden_Tertiary" style="display: none;" class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Tertiary Course:</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You Want" name="ship_course_Tertiary" type="text">
</div>
<div id="hidden_Senior" style="display: none;" class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Senior Course:</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You asdasdWant" name="ship_course_Senior" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showDiv(select){

   if(select.value=='Tertiary'){
    document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "none";
   }
 
 
   if(select.value=='Senior High School'){
    document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "none";
   }

   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">
                        Level:
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="test" onchange="showDiv(this)" name="ship_level"><option value="Primary">Primary</option><option value="Secondary">Secondary</option><option value="Senior High School">Senior High School</option><option value="Tertiary">Tertiary</option></select>
                </div>

<div id="hidden_Tertiary" style="display: none;" class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">
                        Tertiary Course:
                    </label>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You Want" name="ship_course_Tertiary" type="text">
                </div>
                <div id="hidden_Senior" style="display: none;" class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">
                        Senior Course:
                    </label>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You asdasdWant" name="ship_course_Senior" type="text">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be like that

```
 <script>
    function showDiv(select) {
        if (select.value == 'Tertiary') {


                document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "block";              
                document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "none";

        } else if (select.value == 'Senior High School') {

                document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "block";               
                document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "none";
            }


    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have `if` within `if` statements doing the same thing, you don't need these.

Secondly, if you need to only show something specific on each selection, then you start off by turning **everything** off, and then simply turn on each item individually.

```js
function showDiv(select) {
  document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "none";
  if (select.value == 'Tertiary') {
    document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "block";
  } else if (select.value == 'Senior High School') {
    document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Level:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="test" onchange="showDiv(this)" name="ship_level"><option value="Primary">Primary</option><option value="Secondary">Secondary</option><option value="Senior High School">Senior High School</option><option value="Tertiary">Tertiary</option></select>
</div>
<div id="hidden_Tertiary" style="display: none;" class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Tertiary Course:</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You Want" name="ship_course_Tertiary" type="text">
</div>
<div id="hidden_Senior" style="display: none;" class="col-md-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Senior Course:</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You asdasdWant" name="ship_course_Senior" type="text">
</div>
```

You can then improve this with a loop:

```js
function showDiv(select) {
  var subs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-textbox'); // grab all the textbox divs we want by the class
  for( i=0; i < subs.length; i++ ) { // loop through them
    subs[i].style.display = ""; // remove the style so it uses the stylesheet class
  }
  if (select.value == 'Tertiary') {
    document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "block";
  } else if (select.value == 'Senior High School') {
    document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.sub-textbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Level:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="test" onchange="showDiv(this)" name="ship_level"><option value="Primary">Primary</option><option value="Secondary">Secondary</option><option value="Senior High School">Senior High School</option><option value="Tertiary">Tertiary</option></select>
</div>
<div id="hidden_Tertiary" class="col-md-6 form-group sub-textbox">
  <label class="control-label">Tertiary Course:</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You Want" name="ship_course_Tertiary" type="text">
</div>
<div id="hidden_Senior" class="col-md-6 form-group sub-textbox">
  <label class="control-label">Senior Course:</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Course You Want" name="ship_course_Senior" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. It will work

```
function showDiv(select) {
    if (select.value == 'Tertiary') {
        document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hidden_Tertiary').style.display = "none";
    }

    if (select.value == 'Senior High School') {
        document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hidden_Senior').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```